# How to fix "Project 'ListView1' load failed: [MSB4236] The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found. " On Rider with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile-application, rider

I read online that that might happen if the core  dotnet sdk is missing. I installed that and currently my SDKS are as follows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaS54.png)

When  I open the same project in a different laptop it works but I switched to the Rider in my work laptop and it stopped loading. This is the full error message:

2:02 PM Project 'ListView1' load failed: [MSB4236] The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.  C:\Users\ArunasvaBhuyan\Desktop\Project Files\Xamarin\ListView1\ListView1\ListView1\ListView1.csproj at (0:0)

Comment: please do not post duplicate questions

Comment: @Jason I'll delete the older once since I know the error this time

Comment: there are numerous posts about that error on SO and elsewhere.  What have you already tried?

Comment: @Jason I have already tried the solution from the link you sent me ie downloading the core dotnet sdk and adding it to my environment variables

Comment: @Jason my shared Xamarin.Forms project is now loading after I did this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51778267/the-specified-sdk-microsoft-net-sdk-was-not-found however now my .Android and .IOS projects aren't loading the error is