# "Microsoft.NET.Sdk" not found [Visual Studio 2022]

Tags: c#, windows

I am on **Windows 11** and just started out on learning C# and watched a tutorial for a Visual Studio setup. I have the problem when I am trying to open a pre generated C# Project file, that an error shows up.

[image: Error]

I already tried a lot of stuff and searched up but nothing really worked for me.

[image: Current Version]

I looked up and saw that in this post
[:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60482521/21559445)

the guy had the same problem as me and the solution to that was to just get The **.NET Core Workload** but it **doesn't show up** for me.

[image: Here are all Workloads I use]

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue after updating VS 2022 recently. Fixed it by deleting all contents from

`C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet`

https://github.com/dotnet/installer/issues/12616

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after removing VS2019 - but I don't understand why.

My solution was to ensure that in the path variable the entry:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\
```

is listed above:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\
```

I guess removing the x86 path would also do.